# Why nx is throwing error when running storybook

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook, nrwl-nx, nomachine-nx

I'm trying to run my custom react component library through storybook with [nx](https://nx.dev/).

**Expected Result**

Whenever I run `nx run my-lib:storybook` command the storybook will open successfuly.

**Actual results**

After running the command I see the following error:

`webpack built preview 90be684218940772f424 in 162ms Error: NormalModuleFactory.beforeResolve (IgnorePlugin) is no longer a waterfall hook, but a bailing hook instead. Do not return the passed object, but modify it instead. Returning false will ignore the request and results in no module created. at .....`

**Screenshot from nx cloud:**
[image]

***Dependencies of my app***

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.9.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "21.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.15.1",
    "axios": "0.24.0",
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "2.0.1",
    "jszip": "3.7.1",
    "msw": "0.36.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-slick": "0.28.1",
    "react-router-dom": "6.0.2",
    "react-canvas-draw": "1.2.1",
    "react-lottie-player": "1.4.1",
    "react-zoom-pan-pinch": "2.1.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.7",
    "tiny-cookie": "2.3.2",
    "tslib": "2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.16.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.18.6",
    "@craco/craco": "6.4.5",
    "@emotion/babel-plugin": "11.9.2",
    "@nrwl/cli": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/linter": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
    "@nrwl/react": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/storybook": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/web": "14.4.3",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "14.4.3",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.5.9",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "6.5.9",
    "@storybook/core-server": "6.5.9",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "6.5.9",
    "@storybook/react": "6.5.9",
    "@svgr/webpack": "5.4.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "7.0.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "17.0.22",
    "@types/qs": "6.9.7",
    "@types/react": "17.0.37",
    "@types/react-canvas-draw": "1.1.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14",
    "@types/react-slick": "0.23.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.29.0",
    "babel-jest": "27.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "cypress": "9.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "16.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.30.1",
    "husky": "7.0.4",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "jest-mock": "27.5.1",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "12.1.2",
    "nx": "14.4.3",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "sass": "1.44.0",
    "ts-jest": "27.1.4",
    "ts-node": "10.4.0",
    "typescript": "4.5.2",
    "url-loader": "3.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "2.1.4"
  },
```

I think it's something related to webpack versions but it's only a guess.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/18571) reported on the Storybook GitHub. Can you check if it provides a workaround for the issue you are facing? They look similar.